# Cannot create Blackberry sandbox account

Tags: blackberry

Im trying to create a blackberry sandbox account to test my app which has been uploaded to app world(as draft). I was following the document from BB DOCS (http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/25819/Create_a_sandbox_account_1311538_11.jsp...). The first line of the doc says:-

1> On the vendor portal for the BlackBerry App World™ storefront, click Sandbox.

The problem is I cannot find "Sandbox" link on vendor portal for the BlackBerry App World™ storefront(http://appworld.blackberry.com/isvportal/)

Can anyone help me??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to be an admin on the account to be able to view the Sandbox link. It's on the left hand side after "Manage User Accounts" for me. The direct link is https://appworld.blackberry.com/isvportal/sandbox/home.seam?conversationPropagation=end&pageIndex=1

Comment: Hi! I don't get anything such as "Manage User Accounts". But anyway after I am logged in, I can click the link provided by you to see the sandbox accounts. Thank you so much for your reply. I was really stuck with this problem for quite a long time. Thanks again.